# JSON route matching via regex

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Consider I have following JSON object

```
var urls = {
  "GET/users/:id":1,
  "POST/users":0
}
```

and if I have string `"GET/users/10"`. How can I use this as key to get the value from urls JSON i.e. `"GET/users/10"` should match `"GET/users/:id"`.

I don't want to iterate urls JSON and use regex for every key.

Is there a way to access JSON object using regex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There sure is, somehow. It's a terrible idea though. You might want to play with [this](https://www.regextester.com/99141) a little.

Answer (score 3):

Here is something that should work for you. I took some of the pieces from the [Durandal router's RegEx matching logic](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/platforms/HTML/Samples/lib/durandal/js/plugins/router.js) which basically dynamically creates a [regular expression object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) based on a defined route string and then `tests` with it against a passed string.

Here is the working example:

```js
var urls = {
  "GET/users/:id": 1,
  "POST/users": 0
}

const getRouteRegExp = (
  routeString,
  routesAreCaseSensitive = false,
  optionalParam = /\((.*?)\)/g,
  namedParam = /(\(\?)?:\w+/g,
  splatParam = /\*\w+/g,
  escapeRegExp = /[\-{}\[\]+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g
) => {
  routeString = routeString.replace(escapeRegExp, '\\$&')
    .replace(optionalParam, '(?:$1)?')
    .replace(namedParam, function(match, optional) {
      return optional ? match : '([^\/]+)';
    })
    .replace(splatParam, '(.*?)');

  return new RegExp('^' + routeString + '$', routesAreCaseSensitive ? undefined : 'i');
}

const getRouteByString = (string) => {
  var resultArr = Object.entries(urls).find(([k, v]) => {
    var regEx = getRouteRegExp(k)
    return regEx.test(string)
  }) || []
  return resultArr[0]
}

console.log(getRouteByString('GET/users/10'))
console.log(getRouteByString('POST/users'))
console.log(getRouteByString('POST/users2'))
```

So what you have is the `getRouteRegExp` function which is the main thing here which would compose a regular expression object based on a passed `route`.

After that we go and for each existing route defined in `urls` we create one RegExp and try to match it against the provided `string route`. This is what the `find` does. If one is found we return it.

Since we are doing [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) we return the 0 index which contains the result.

Since this comes straight from the Durandal bits it supports all the route expressions that are built in Durandal ... like:

- Static route: `tickets`
- Parameterized: `tickets/:id`
- Optional Parameter: `users(/:id)`
- Splat Route: `settings*details`

You can read more about [Durandal Router here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html)

Comment: Thanks @Akrion, The above solution is very helpful. :)

Comment: Awesome. If this solves your problem you should accept it as the answer so others can find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I can understand is your key is dynamic, so you can do something like this:

```
var urls = {
  "GET/users/:id":1,
  "POST/users":0
}
let id = 10

const yourValue = urls["GET/users/" + id]
```

Comment: with this `"GET/users/"+id` it will create `GET/users/10`, which will not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to

```
var urls = {
  "GET/users/:id":1,
  "POST/users":0
}
var regex = /"([^"]+?)"\s*/g;
var urlsJson = JSON.stringify(urls);
let result = regex.exec(urlsJson)
if(result && result.length > 0) {
  var keyJson = result[1];
  var value = urls[keyJson]
  console.log('value', value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
const urls = (id) => ({
   [`GET/users/${id}`]:1,
    "POST/users":0,   
});

console.log(urls(2));
```

I hope it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The json would look fine, just do a replace on the url, so replace the ending integer with :id and then you have the key by which you can directly access the value in the json.
So:

```js
var url = "GET/users/10";

var urls = {
  "GET/users/:id":1,
  "POST/users":0
}


url = url.replace(/users\/\d+/, 'users/:id');
console.log(urls[url]);
```

Do as many replaces on the url to convert all possible url's to the keys in your json.